# Save File From URL that has a redirection

Tags: php, twilio, mms

I am trying to save a local copy of all the media that is sent through Twilio.

```
$media = file_get_contents($mediaUrl);
$filename = $mediaSid . '.' . $fileExtension;
file_put_contents(public_path('storage/mms/' . $filename), $media);
```

The problem is `file_get_contents` does not seem to be following the redirection so I get a file that contains TwiML. I have an example below of what I keep getting. My question is what function do I need to use so that it follows the redirection and I get the actual data of the media rather than the XML?

The file that is created:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TwilioResponse><Media><Sid/><AccountSid>AC....</AccountSid><ParentSid/><ContentType/><DateCreated>Fri, 08 Nov 2019 01:49:02 +0000</DateCreated><DateUpdated>Fri, 08 Nov 2019 01:49:02 +0000</DateUpdated><Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC.../Messages/MM.../Media/ME...</Uri></Media></TwilioResponse>
```

Comment: Looks like there's not a redirection at all, and you need to parse the XML.

Comment: Going to the mediaURL manually redirects to the media. According to Chrome web inspector, it has two redirections. First a 307 then a 301.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (php 7.3.4-2) - `file_get_contents` follows both redirections on my machine. It must be something with your headers, maybe even the user agent? Have you tried to get this working with a request tester (postman / insomnia)?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm not sure what's going wrong here, just wanted to follow the discussion and help if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use libcurl rather than file_get_contents to work around this particular issue, according to Twilio support.

The reason for this is the Twilio sends a temporary URL which is over 1024 characters and is just ignored.

```
$mediaUrl = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxx/Messages/MMxxxxxxxxxxx/Media/MExxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$accountSid = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$authToken = "...";

$curl = curl_init();
$outfile = fopen('temp.jpg', 'w+');
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $mediaUrl,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$accountSid:$authToken",
    CURLOPT_FILE => $outfile
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```